# android-wear\x86\devices.xml cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using Windows 7.

I already installed ADT+SDK in eclipse. But when I open eclipse showing below error messages. Help me to resolve this, please.

> android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, Don't worry. When I downloaded API 22, I faced the same problem. Deleting 2 files solved the problem.

Delete the below mentioned files and restart Eclipse.

```
    1.Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image.
    2.Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image.
```

open SDK manager and select these two files if they are already exists and delete them

Comment: This does clear the error message, but possibly you will require these if you are developing Wear on API 22